# Spring + GAE incorrect initialization of spring container

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to write an aoolication enabled with Spring + GAE but I've faced with a very strange problem.

For persistence layer I user JPA with following persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" 
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastorePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true" />
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true" />
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Also I have spring config file with following declaration:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="transactions-optional" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="datastoreService" class="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory" factory-method="getDatastoreService" />

    <bean id="memcacheServiceUser" class="com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceFactory" factory-method="getMemcacheService">
        <constructor-arg value="UserCache"/>
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

And finnaly I have DAO component which is marked ad @Repository and extends JpaDaoSupport this bean configured to be scanned with

And after attempt to initialize that DAO bean I receive following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: entityManagerFactory or jpaTemplate is required
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.JpaDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(JpaDaoSupport.java:120)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$5.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1467)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1465)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
... 30 more
```

Then I've looked at the log and I can see that entityManagerFactory creates successfully befor DAO init, but just before actual start of initialization of DAO object, spring just destroys all singletons including this one. There is a lot of logs but I defenitly sure that entityManagerFactory creates as well, the one thing that is very strange to me it is why spring destroys all singletons with following log message:

```
    INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1594a88: defining beans [org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,datastoreService,memcacheServiceUser,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,userDaoJpa,employeeDS,messageSource]; root of factory hierarchy
Jan 14, 2011 11:12:12 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter destroy
FINE: Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'
Jan 14, 2011 11:12:12 AM org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean destroy
INFO: Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'transactions-optional'
Jan 14, 2011 11:12:12 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoJpa' defined in file
```

Comment: The singletons are being destroyed because the startup failed. It's not relevant to your problem.  Also, please show us the full stack trace of the `IllegalArgumentException`, not just the snippet you posted.

Answer (score 0):

The class JpaDaoSupport expects you to set the `EntityManagerFactory` or `JpaTemplate` on construction. Something like this should do it:

```
@Repository
public class YourDAOImpl extends JpaDaoSupport implements YourDAO
{
    @Autowired
    public YourDAOImpl(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory)
    {
        setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically inject the entity manager using below.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
public ClaseDaoImpl(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
}
```

Each implemented by Dao.